# adding AWS Lambda as target using AWS SDK for event bridge rule

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

I am using serverless framework and the AWS Node.js SDK for adding scheduled cron expression based rule to default event bus.

```
 eventBridge.putRule(params, function (err, data) {...
```

After that I add target to this rule.

```
const params = {
    Rule: data.ruleName,
    Targets: [ 
        {
            Arn: process.env.SCHEDULED_EVENT_LAMBDA_ARN, /* required */
            Id: process.env.SCHEDULED_EVENT_LAMBDA_ID, /* required */
            Input: JSON.stringify(someData)
        },
        
    ],
    
};

eventBridge.putTargets(params, function (err, data) {...
```

adding target is successful on the dynamically created scheduled cron rule on event bridge but when I navigate to lambda dashboard it does not seems like the triggering layer is updated and eventually the lambda function is not triggered.

The AWS SDK documentation for event bridge `putTargets` is mentioning:

**`For AWS Lambda and Amazon SNS resources, EventBridge relies on resource-based policies`**

So if the resource policy is the issue(not confirmed) is there any configuration regarding resource policy which I can set in `serverless.yml` file for a specific function that allows event-bridge service to add layer to deployed targated lambda function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for dynamic generation you can use the [AddPermission](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_AddPermission.html) to add the necessary permissions.

```js
function addPermission ({ lambdaArn, restApiId }) {
 const { region, namespace } = parseArn(lambdaArn)

 const params = {
  Action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction',
  FunctionName: lambdaArn,
  Principal: 'events.amazonaws.com',
  StatementId: `scheduleName`,
  SourceArn: `RuleARN`
 }

 return lambda.addPermission(params).promise()
}
```

If you are using `serverless` framework.

```yaml
functions:
  myFunction:
    handler: index.handler
    events:
      - eventBridge:
          schedule: rate(10 minutes)
          input:
            key1: value1
```

The above definition simply create the rule and add your lambda as the target. It will take care of the necessary permissions as well whichever is needed.

[Setting up event pattern matching](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/event-bridge/)

[EventBridge Use Cases and Examples](https://www.serverless.com/blog/eventbridge-use-cases-and-tutorial)

[Schedule](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/schedule/)

Comment: the scheduled cron jobs are dynamically added via an api on eventbridge. I think this is declaring in advance for a predefined event.

Comment: @UditBhardwaj so what you want is to allow `eventbridge` to trigger your lambda correct ?

Comment: Yes but when a new rule is added it adds the lambda as its target. This works but the Event bridge trigger layer is not added to the lambda. Seems like the event-bridge API from AWS-SDK adds the target but cannot update the lambda deployment.

Comment: whereas adding the event rule target directly from AWS management console under the event rule section of Event bridge service (logged in as root user) the lambda function updates and shows event bridge layer.

Comment: @UditBhardwaj then you can simply add the permissions for allowing `eventbridge` to invoke the lambda. [Is it possible to use configure Lambda Function Resource-based Policies using serverless framework?](https://forum.serverless.com/t/is-it-possible-to-use-configure-lambda-function-resource-based-policies-using-serverless-framework/4932/8)

Comment: @UditBhardwaj basically you are missing this part in the above flow [Use the following add-permission command to trust the EventBridge service principal (events.amazonaws.com) and scope permissions to the rule with the specified Amazon Resource Name (ARN](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/run-lambda-schedule.html#schedule-create-rule)

Comment: so I have to add permission on the lambda function for each new created rule every time before adding the lambda function as its target?

Comment: @UditBhardwaj yes,  you can use `*` in the resources section or create policy based on tags. In that case you just have the tags in the rule and policy will allow it. [AWS global condition context keys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html#AvailableKeys)

Comment: @UditBhardwaj you should accept this answer as solution. I can confirm that it works for me.  I did dynamic generation with this simple implementation and all just fine.